How to properly use security tokens in a website with a second Web API?
I have a challenging setup where I have to develop a Web API where users can log in and do specific tasks. This login goes through JWT and this works well, but is just the first step.
The API runs on an internal server with no access to the Internet. So I can't call third-party services from it. The host is on the Intranet in a separate network but it can be accessed from the second project. It's main usage goes through local applications in the local network.
The JWT it uses is signed and encrypted and is used to identify the user with every API call. Often, it needs access to the user-related data.
The second project is a website that exposes some of the API functions to the outside world. It has access to the Internet through one network, and to the Web API through another network. This is also working fine.
Now, this project has some very high security demands so the JWT is only valid for two minutes, then it expires. The internal applications just have a timer that use the JWT to refresh itself every 90 seconds. I could do this in JavaScript in the browser too, but that would have to go through the site first before it goes to the API.
Now, I understand the concept of refresh tokens and access tokens but I don't think that would be practical here. If you can log in the site then you can do anything that the site provides. And the site is limited in what it can do.
So I wonder what the best approach would be to handle this security. The site cannot read the JWT as the JWT is encrypted. The site is not even allowed to read the content, but just has to pass it around.
My idea is to just refresh the token with every API call that the site makes. But that could mean that there would be many tokens that would be valid at the same time, albeit just 2 minutes each. Or maybe some other solution? I can't change the API as then various applications might crash. So, what would be a good approach to manage this JWT?
